# Modules config file

Tags: yii2

I'm my api module's module.php file, i added this

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function init()
{
    parent::init();

     // custom initialization code goes here
     \Yii::configure($this, require __DIR__ . '/config/main.php');
}
```

in my controller i have this

```
public function actionIndex()
{
   dd(Yii::$app->getModule('payment')->params['data']);

}
```

in my modules `main.php i have this

```
$params = ['data' => [ ... ]];

    if (YII_ENV == 'dev') {


if (YII_ENV == 'dev') {
    $params = array_merge(
        require __DIR__ . '/../../../../common/config/params.php',
        require __DIR__ . '/../../../../common/config/params-local.php',
        require __DIR__ . '/params.php',
    );
} else {
    $params = array_merge(
        require __DIR__ . '/../../../../common/config/params.php',
        require __DIR__ . '/params.php',
    );
}

return [
    'params' => $params,
];
```

I'm getting this error `Undefined array key "data"` Any one know what im missing here, i'm  trying to create a module config. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a  main.php in module (there is in app/config).
in each module there is a Module.php  class in modules/your_module  scaffolding

If you need  a specific $params array for the a module  you should declare the params var
and assign your values or in declaration or in init() function

```
class Module extends \yii\base\Module
{
    public $params = [];

   .....
   ......

 /**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function init()
{
    parent::init();

     // custom initialization code goes here
     $params['data'] = [......]; 
     
}
```

Comment: i put my `params` array in a file and initiated code like this `$this->params = require __DIR__ . '/config/params.php';` but in my controller i get an empty array when i dd() this `dd(Yii::$app->getModule('payment')->params);` and dd(Yii::$app->getModule('payment')->params['data']); gives me an `Undefined array key` error. on my params.php file i have this `return ['data'=> [...]];`